# GCC how to stop false positive warning implicit-function-declaration for functions in ROM?

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller

I want to get rid of all implicit-function-declaration warnings in my codebase. But there is a problem because some functions are 
 programmed into the microcontroller ROM at the factory and during linking a linker script provides only the function address. These functions are called by code in the SDK.

During compilation gcc of course emits the warning `implicit-function-declaration`. How can I get rid of this warning?

To be clear I understand why the warning is there and what does it mean. But in this particular case the developers of SDK guarantee that the code will work with implicit rules (i.e. implicit function takes only ints and returns an int). So this warning is a false positive.

This is gnu-C-99 only, no c++.

Ideas:

- Guess the argument types, write a prototype in a header and include that?
- Tell gcc to treat such functions as false positive with some gcc attribute?

Comment: Is this C code or C++?  Are namespaces involved?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` to your cflags?

Comment: @StephenNewell I want to resolve the false warnings, not ignore them. Because I dont want to miss the real warnings.

Comment: You can put a function declaration `int name();` for each one.  Don't put a prototype.

Comment: @M.M I thought I would have to do at least for example  "int name(int, int)" if the function takes two args to account for the number of arguments, no?

Comment: No you don't have to do that (and in fact you shouldn't, if the functions are designed to be called without it)

Comment: You forgot to post the exact example code that produces these error messages.

Comment: The simplest way to handle this is to create a header file (and include it in each file where functions are called)  for every function in ROM, etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either create a prototype function in a header, or suppress the warnings with the following:

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-function-declaration"
/* line where GCC complains about implicit function declaration */
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Actually this looks like a good suggestion because it solves the problem locally i.e. within one file. Nice trick!

Comment: More than that, it will only suppress warnings on the lines between when you `push` and `pop`, so the compiler can still issue `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` elsewhere in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Write a small program that generates a header file `romfunctions.h` from the linker script, with a line like this

```
int rom_function();
```

for each symbol defined by the ROM.  Run this program from your Makefiles.  Change all of the files that use these functions to include `romfunctions.h`.  This way, if the linker script changes, you don't have to update the header file by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Because most of my programming expertise was acquired by self-study, I intentionally have become somewhat anal about resolving non-fatal warnings, specifically to avoid picking up bad coding habits. But, this has revealed to me that such bad coding habits are quite common, even from formally trained programmers. In particular, for someone like me who is also anal about NOT using MS Windows, my self-study of so-called platform-independent code such as OpenGL and Vulkan has revealed a WORLD of bad coding habits, particularly as I examine code written assuming the student was using Visual Studio and a Windows C/C++ compiler.

Recently, I encountered NUMEROUS non-fatal warnings as I designed an Ubuntu Qt Console implementation of an online example of how to use SPIR-V shaders with OpenGL. I finally threw in the towel and added the following lines to my qmake .PRO file to get rid of the non-fatal-warnings (after, first, studying each one and convincing myself it could be safely ignored) :

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -Wno-implicit-function-declaration 
-Wno-address-of-packed-member

Answer (score 0):

[Completely written due to commends]

You are compiling the vendor SDK with your own code. This is not typically what you want to do.

What you do is you build their SDK files with `gcc -c -Wno-implicit-function-declaration` and and your own files with `gcc -c` or possibly `gcc -o output all-your-c-files all-their-o-files`.

Comment: The code inside the SDK calls some unspecified functions in ROM that (as I understand) should not be used by application developers directly. So they dont provide the header for those ROM functions. Only their fixed address in a link script. :(

Comment: @user10607: Then why are you calling them?

Comment: @user10607: Are you trying to build their provided library?

Comment: I am not calling them. They just make for about 300 implicti-function-declaration warnings during compilation. This is noise behind which real errors can easily go unnoticed.

Comment: @user10607: Replaced answer based on your comments

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I am bugfixing the SDK, because its a really cheap  vendor :) Some of the warnings for their own code were actually *real* bugs.

Comment: @user10607: Given your vendor's code quality attitude I'm not surprised. I sense you're in too deep for "switch vendors". Maybe start writing prototypes is right after all.

Answer (score 0):

C does not require that declarations be prototypes, so you can get rid of the problem (which should be a **hard error**, not a warning, since implicit declarations are not valid C) by using a non-prototype declaration, which requires only knowing the return type. For example:

```
int foo();
```

Since "implicit declarations" were historically treated as returning `int`, you can simply use `int` for all of them.

Comment: Note however that non-prototype function declarations is listed as obsolete in C, so it's not a good idea to use them still.

Comment: @Lundin: Unfortunately there are dome things you can do with them that can be done in no other way.

Answer (score -4):

If you are using C program, use

```
#include <stdio.h>
```